# Apache Spark on Databricks Caused by: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

Whenever I attempt to excute any command (for example %fs rm -r /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/), on Apache Spark on Databricks Community Edition I get the following error:

java.lang.Exception: An error occurred while initializing the REPL. Please check whether there are conflicting Scala libraries or JARs attached to the cluster, such as Scala 2.11 libraries attached to Scala 2.10 cluster (or vice-versa).

When I look into the error logs I see the problem is caused by:

**Caused by: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.**

The full error is as follows:

````
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.initSpark(DriverILoop.scala:60)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.initializeSpark(DriverILoop.scala:185)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.createInterpreterForWeb(DriverILoop.scala:165)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.createInterpreter(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:417)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.interp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:434)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:714)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:667)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:396)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1390)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1242)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.compileSourcesKeepingRun(IMain.scala:439)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.DriverIMain.compileSourcesKeepingRun(DriverIMain.scala:305)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.compileAndSaveRun(IMain.scala:862)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.compile(IMain.scala:820)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.DriverIMain.bind(DriverIMain.scala:84)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.bind(DriverILoop.scala:191)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DatabricksILoop$class.initSpark(DatabricksILoop.scala:87)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.initSpark(DriverILoop.scala:60)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.initializeSpark(DriverILoop.scala:185)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.createInterpreterForWeb(DriverILoop.scala:165)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.createInterpreter(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:417)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.interp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:434)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:714)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:667)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:396)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```

Any thoughts on how to go about resolving this issue?
````

Comment: check that you don't have incompatible libraries added to your cluster

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm not sure what libraries are required. Is there a way of checking what libraries are need in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any additional libraries installed into the cluster, or it happens just on empty cluster?

Comment: Hi Alex, it happens on empty cluster.

Comment: It's very strange, as it happens with every new cluster that I spin up.

Comment: I would appreciate any additiona thoughts you have on this one. Cheers

Comment: unfortunately I don't have any ideas right now

Comment: Check the java version used. 1.8 is the best option now.

Comment: Hi @SuhasNM, thanks for reaching out. Would you please show me how to check the java version used and how to update the version? Or provide a link showing how its done?

Comment: execute "java -version" in command prompt / linux terminal. If you are executing code in intellij or any other IDE, check the project settings and SDK used. If you are submitting it to a spark master, check the java version used in the spark master using the same command.

Answer (score 0):

execute `java -version` in command prompt / linux terminal. If you are executing code in intellij or any other IDE, check the project settings and SDK used. If you are submitting it to a spark master, check the java version used in the spark master using the same command.

Java version 8 is compatible with scala 2.11 / 2.12 / 2.13

Comment: he clearly wrote "Apache Spark on Databricks Community Edition"...

Comment: Any additional assistance with this will be very much appreciated.